# SONAR not working on Web Browser

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to access Sonar through web browser. I already started it on my terminal but when I try to access it on web browser through , it shows nothing. However, the status shows Sonar is running. How can I make it running on the web browser ?

The configuration for Sonar web is:

```
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1

sonar.web.context=/sonar

sonar.web.port=9000
```

Answer (score 8):

`sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1`

I think this is the problematic line in your conf. This line indicates which IP address the Web Server will bind to. If you set it to `127.0.0.1`, then Server will only respond if you reach to it through the IP `127.0.0.1`, that is, you'll only be able to access it from `localhost`, though *IPv4*. (Your browser will probably prefer IPv6, with `::1` being the host)

Comment out the line (prepending a *#*) in order to have it listen to every IP the machine is called by.

---

If you can verify access from the host machine itself, but the above doesn't help, then you might want to check if your firewall is blocking requests.

Comment: If we want to use the sonar page outside the machine, then use

sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

Answer (score 6):

With the settings you provided, make sure you're using this URL and trying to access the server from the same box: `http://127.0.0.1:9000/sonar/`

If you're attempting to reach `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` and getting the empty page, it's due to the `sonar.web.context` value you're using.

Note: unless you're hosting SonarQube in an external webserver, you don't need to set the `sonar.web.context`, in which case, you would just go to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/`

If this URL isn't working for you, I would suggest looking at the SonarQube server logs in the `/logs` folder to determine if there were any errors starting the server.  If so, you'll want to update this posting with the details from the log, including which operating system you're running.

Comment: Can you share the full path of the "/logs" folder